# How to suppress "Redundant 'let' call can be removed"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a file with loads of redundant `x?.let { it.something() }` and I want to keep them this way.

How do I suppress the warning? IDE doesn't offer suppression here. I've looked into [Errors.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/diagnostics/Errors.java) and [DefaultErrorMessages.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/diagnostics/rendering/DefaultErrorMessages.java) but nothing seemed to fit.

More general question: what arguments are supported by `@Suppress` annotation?

Answer (score 4):

Like I said in the comment on the other question, just use the IDE to suppress warnings - every warning popup has a 'More Options' link, or you can put the cursor on the highlighted bit of code and do Alt+Enter (or whatever) or click the lightbulb. Then you'll get a list of actions for the warning, and you can hit the right arrow to get options for each one - the main action (the *"fix it"* one) has options that allow you to suppress the warning instead:

[image: A screenshot of the menu with the suppression options visible]

There's no defined set of possible things you can suppress, because things like lint checks can be added to over time (or by using libraries that provide their own checks), IDE features can be expanded, etc. [Like the language spec says](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/annotations.html#kotlin.suppress):

> `kotlin.Suppress` is used to optionally mark any piece of code as suppressing some language feature, such as a compiler warning, an IDE mechanism or a language feature. **The names of features which one can suppress with this annotation are implementation-defined**, as is the processing of this annotation itself.

So it's better to let the IDE do it automatically since it knows the `name` of the inspection being triggered when it warns you about a thing, so it can create the appropriate annotation.

---

Generally you shouldn't be suppressing these anyway, they're highlighting code that has issues, is unnecessarily complex, or that isn't actually what you think it is (like in my example there, I'm treating the value as potentially null - but it's not actually a nullable type). It's better to fix the issue rather than suppress it and leave the intent ambiguous. Even if you know what it means and what it's supposed to do, someone who comes along later might be confused by it (possibly Future You!). There are some situations where it's necessary or useful, but generally speaking the warnings are there for a good reason.